# Obscure error says my component name begins with a zero

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting an obscure error that my component name is zero. But none of my components have a zero for a name. This error is hard to track down. Anyone know what the problem could be so I can move in the right direction to tackle it.

> vendor.js:66537 [Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "0". Component names can only contain alphanumeric characters and the hyphen, and must start with a letter.

Heres more information on the error:

[image]

**Edit**: More information:

I have a unique project structure. I have single file components. And each component is split into 2 files like so:

Home.vue:

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<style lang="scss">
    ...
</style>

<script src="./home.js"></script>
```

home.js:

```
export default {
    ...
}
```

**Edit: debug capture**

[image]

**Edit: home.js**

```
import RecentPostsWidget from './widgets/RecentPosts'
import PagesWidget from './widgets/Pages'

export default {
    components: {
        RecentPostsWidget,
        PagesWidget
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint inside `validateComponentName` to see how it sees your module?

Comment: @raina77ow I've added a screen capture. The error occurs on router-view

Comment: Can we see the contents of home.js?

Comment: @Borjante please see my edit :)

Comment: As suspected, no name defined. Let's try adding one

Comment: @JakeM Not sure, but i think you need to add `.vue` at the end of the imports, so `import PagesWidget from './widgets/Pages.vue'`

Comment: @JakeM Any Solutions?

Comment: @sazr have you found the answer?

Answer (score 58):

I had the same error and it was caused by use of array instead of object in the components.
This is how it should look

```
components: {
  RecentPostsWidget,
  PagesWidget
}
```

This is how I had it when the error appeared:

```
components: [
  RecentPostsWidget,
  PagesWidget
]
```

Comment: Great! This answer should be set as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
components: {
    RecentPostsWidget,
    PagesWidget
}
```

with

```
components: {
    recentPostsWidget: RecentPostsWidget,
    pagesWidget: PagesWidget
}
```

Answer (score 2):

look somewhere for a component that you are using braces: [] and change them to {}
Example:

```
components: [
     Logo,
     Nav
   ],
```

Switch to:

```
components: {
     Logo,
     Nav
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a name to the component?

home.js

```
import RecentPostsWidget from './widgets/RecentPosts'
import PagesWidget from './widgets/Pages'

export default {
    name: 'p-components-home',
    components: {
        RecentPostsWidget,
        PagesWidget
    }
}
```

Comment: is the name always required?

Comment: I'm not sure, what I'm sure is that it is a best practice. Does it keep throwing the same error with a name?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the same error occurs when I add a name

Comment: Interesting, now just for debugging purposes.
What happens if you put the contents of home.js inside the Home.vue template file and removing the reference to the home.js file?

Comment: The issue for me was that the name string had a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was dumb enough to name my component like

```js
export default {
  components: 'footer',
}
```

Instead of :

```js
export default {
  name: 'Footer',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `.vue` at the end of imports of the components

```
import RecentPostsWidget from './widgets/RecentPosts.vue'
import PagesWidget from './widgets/Pages.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        RecentPostsWidget,
        PagesWidget
    }
}
```