# [Vue warn]: Invalid component name after uglify

Tags: webpack, vue.js, uglifyjs

I'm using vue + webpack. While in development mode (hot-reload with expressjs server) everything works fine. In production setup my `output.js` gets obscured which leads to Vue warnings:

- `[Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: hr`
- `[Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "$s". Component names can only contain alphanumeric characters and the hyphen, and must start with a letter.`

[image]

**question**: Is there a way to make webpack + uglifyjs compile code so those warning disappear.

I understand that I can remove warning with `optimization: { minimize: false}` but I still want to obscure my code in production.

Comment: No. Your problem is not related to Webpack. Problem is you can't have own, custom components with names like br, li, $s, $l. Rename them.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky I don't have such components. Furthermore I specified that I don't have this issue with `optimization: { minimize: false},`. How comes it's not related?

Comment: have you listed components using object notation. see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357473/5036579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I was able to solve my issue as @Charles Dominic mention it turned out that [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) that I used w/o name provided is using [components using object notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792383/obscure-error-says-my-component-name-begins-with-a-zero/52357473#52357473). I should have specified component name in decorator:

```
  @Component({
    name: 'test',
   })
```